# Java modification of the value of the object parameter

Tags: java, object

Should'nt `p.name = "EJava";` being altered after method `anotherMethod(p);` was invoked ?
Can anyone explain why this code returns :

```
anotherMethod
EJava
someMethod
someMethod
```

instead of :

```
anotherMethod
anotherMethod
someMethod
someMethod
```

Class Person

```
class Person {
   public String name;
   public int height;
}
```

Tester

```
class EJavaGuruPassObjects1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = "EJava";
        anotherMethod(p);
        System.out.println(p.name);
        someMethod(p);
        System.out.println(p.name);
    }

    static void someMethod(Person p) {
        p.name = "someMethod";
        System.out.println(p.name);
    }

    static void anotherMethod(Person p) {
        p = new Person();
        p.name = "anotherMethod";
        System.out.println(p.name);
    }
}
```

Should'nt `p.name = "EJava";` being altered after method `anotherMethod(p);` was invoked?

Comment: You create a new Person that has nothing to do with the one you've passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `Person` object in `anotherMethod()`.It should be

```
static void anotherMethod(Person p) {
   p.name = "anotherMethod";
   System.out.println(p.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry this is a dumb question but i'm new

Comment: @George: If you have any doubts, check out this previous question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Object reference variables are passed by value in Java (like everything else). In someMethod(), the name of the actual object to which p points is changed. In anotherMethod(), it points to a new Person object with its information changed. Your original reference is unchanged. Outside of these methods, you still have some variable pointing to the original `Person` object.

It's best to think about these variables as pointers. You create a `Person p`, and it points to this new object with a name you've decided on. Let's say you create another variable, `Person x` and set `x = p`. Now x and p point to the same object. Changing one will reflect itself in both variables. However, if you then do `p = new Person()`, then p will point to a NEW object, but x will still point to that original object first referenced by p.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry this is a dumb question but i'm new

Answer (score 0):

Java does not use references in the C++ sense. so your method

```
static void anotherMethod(Person p) {
p = new Person();
p.name = "anotherMethod";
System.out.println(p.name);
}
}
```

does **nothing** to the `p` variable, it simply creates new object, calls it (temporarly) p and forgets about it once the method is completed.

p is just a **copy** of the reference to the actual object, Java **always** passes arguments as **copies**.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry this is a dumb question but i'm new

Answer (score 0):

Java passes all objects by copies of the reference, not by reference.

That means that `p` in `anotherMethod` is a copy of the reference `p` that lives in the main method. If you assign the `p` that lives in `anotherMethod` is has no impact on what `p` in your main method references, because it's just a copy.